# Por que Between não traz a resposta certa

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Tenho uma tabela especifica com os dados que quais eu faço a busca (`sales_flat_order`) onde coluna `status` tem entre outros valores
(`'entregue'`, `'entregue_pd'`, `'entregue_pd_pago'`, `'avaliacao_solicitado'`, `'avaliado_negativamente'`, `'avaliado_positivamente'`), mas quando uso o `between` não traz as informações corretas uma vez que ao ser consultado separados tenho retorno de todas este é o *script*

```sql
(
SELECT entity_id, status FROM sales_flat_order where 
(status between 'entregue_pd_pago' 
and 'entregue' 
and 'entregue_pd_pago'
and 'avaliacao_solicitado'
and 'avaliado_negativamente'
and 'avaliado_positivamente'
);
)
```

Estou usando o MySQL Workbench.

Comment: BETWEEN serve para verificar se um valor está em um intervalo. Por exemplo, `year BETWEEN 2015 AND 2019`. Não fez sentido algum no que você tentou fazer, muito menos ficou claro qual era a sua intenção. Você quer que retorne o registro caso o `status` seja um desses listados?

Comment: Você está fazendo o uso errado do `between` você está tentando fazer um `IN (value1,value2,value3,value4)`

Comment: gostaria de retornar os id´s que estivessem com aqueles status mas como vc mesmo mencionou o in deve resolver. Anderson Carlos Woss

Answer (score 4):

Você está fazendo um uso errado do `between`.

**between** serve para verificar se um valor está entre 2 valores. Exemplo

```
select * from numeros where valor between 0 and 10
```

O retorno do select acima seria

```
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
```

para fazer uma verificação se um valor está dentro de uma lista específica de valores você precisa usar o `IN()`

```
SELECT entity_id, status FROM sales_flat_order 
where status IN (
    'entregue_pd_pago', 
    'entregue',
    'entregue_pd_pago',
    'avaliacao_solicitado',
    'avaliado_negativamente',
    'avaliado_positivamente'
);
```